# TypeError: 'range' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization, seaborn

I have been plotting some plots and then I received the above error for the code below:

```
    lag = range(0, 31)
    djia_acf = []
    for l in lag:
        djia_acf.append(djia_df['Close'].autocorr(l))


    plt.figure(figsize = (5.5, 5.5))
    g = sns.pointplot(x=lag, y=djia_acf, markers = '.')
    g.set_title('Autocorrelation function for DJIA')
    g.set_xlabel('Lag in terms of number of trading days')
    g.set_ylabel('Autocorrelation Function')
    g.set_xticklabels(lag, rotation = 90)

TypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-3ca28bdcaeea> in <module>()
      1 plt.figure(figsize = (5.5, 5.5))
----> 2 g = sns.pointplot(x=lag, y=djia_acf, markers = '.')
      3 g.set_title('Autocorrelation function for DJIA')
      4 g.set_xlabel('Lag in terms of number of trading days')
      5 g.set_ylabel('Autocorrelation Function')

/home/aspiring1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in pointplot(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, estimator, ci, n_boot, units, markers, linestyles, dodge, join, scale, orient, color, palette, ax, errwidth, capsize, **kwargs)
   3065                             estimator, ci, n_boot, units,
   3066                             markers, linestyles, dodge, join, scale,
-> 3067                             orient, color, palette, errwidth, capsize)
   3068 
   3069     if ax is None:

/home/aspiring1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in __init__(self, x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, estimator, ci, n_boot, units, markers, linestyles, dodge, join, scale, orient, color, palette, errwidth, capsize)
   1607         """Initialize the plotter."""
   1608         self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient,
-> 1609                                  order, hue_order, units)
   1610         self.establish_colors(color, palette, 1)
   1611         self.estimate_statistic(estimator, ci, n_boot)

/home/aspiring1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in establish_variables(self, x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order, units)
    201                 # Group the numeric data
    202                 plot_data, value_label = self._group_longform(vals, groups,
--> 203                                                               group_names)
    204 
    205                 # Now handle the hue levels for nested ordering

/home/aspiring1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in _group_longform(self, vals, grouper, order)
    243 
    244         # Group the val data
--> 245         grouped_vals = vals.groupby(grouper)
    246         out_data = []
    247         for g in order:

/home/aspiring1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in groupby(self, by, axis, level, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, **kwargs)
   4269         return groupby(self, by=by, axis=axis, level=level, as_index=as_index,
   4270                        sort=sort, group_keys=group_keys, squeeze=squeeze,
-> 4271                        **kwargs)
   4272 
   4273     def asfreq(self, freq, method=None, how=None, normalize=False,

/home/aspiring1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in groupby(obj, by, **kwds)
   1624         raise TypeError('invalid type: %s' % type(obj))
   1625 
-> 1626     return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
   1627 
   1628 

/home/aspiring1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in __init__(self, obj, keys, axis, level, grouper, exclusions, selection, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, **kwargs)
    390                                                     level=level,
    391                                                     sort=sort,
--> 392                                                     mutated=self.mutated)
    393 
    394         self.obj = obj

/home/aspiring1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in _get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort, mutated)
   2636                         sort=sort,
   2637                         in_axis=in_axis) \
-> 2638             if not isinstance(gpr, Grouping) else gpr
   2639 
   2640         groupings.append(ping)

/home/aspiring1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in __init__(self, index, grouper, obj, name, level, sort, in_axis)
   2418                     t = self.name or str(type(self.grouper))
   2419                     raise ValueError("Grouper for '%s' not 1-dimensional" % t)
-> 2420                 self.grouper = self.index.map(self.grouper)
   2421                 if not (hasattr(self.grouper, "__len__") and
   2422                         len(self.grouper) == len(self.index)):

/home/aspiring1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in map(self, mapper)
   2725         """
   2726         from .multi import MultiIndex
-> 2727         mapped_values = self._arrmap(self.values, mapper)
   2728         attributes = self._get_attributes_dict()
   2729         if mapped_values.size and isinstance(mapped_values[0], tuple):

pandas/_libs/algos_common_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.algos.arrmap_int64 (pandas/_libs/algos.c:41758)()

TypeError: 'range' object is not callable

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7f1fa7c2ab70>
```

In the above code I'm just trying to plot a pointplot using seaborn, but it is giving error of range object isn't callable, I've seen a similar post which had the error

> "list object is not callable"

But, here I can't see anywhere where my range object **lag** has been called.
Using x = np.array(lag) gives me the required plot with the below output as extra, don't know why?

```
[<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7d38208>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7d38ef0>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c61208>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c61cc0>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c696d8>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c711d0>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c71c88>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c75780>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c7c278>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c7cd30>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c02828>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c08320>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c08dd8>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c0c8d0>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c123c8>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c12e80>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c1a978>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c1e470>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c1ef28>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c25a20>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c2a518>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c2afd0>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c31ac8>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c385c0>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c3d0b8>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c3db70>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7bc5668>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7bc9160>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7bc9c18>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7bce710>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7bd4208>]
```

I've made plots using matplotlib.pyplot which take range object as x values as given below:

```
inflation = pd.read_excel('inflation-consumer-prices-annual.xlsx', parse_dates=['Year'])
plt.figure(figsize=(5.5, 5.5))
plt.plot(range(1960,2017), inflation['India'], linestyle='-', marker='*',
color='r')
plt.plot(range(1960,2017), inflation['United States'], linestyle='-',
marker='.', color='b')
plt.legend(['India','United States'], loc=1)
plt.title('Inflation in Consumer Price Index')
plt.ylabel('Inflation')
plt.xlabel('Years')
```

Thus, I can't why I am getting the TypeError, since it works with matplotlib.pyplot and range object being called doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Please always include the **complete** error traceback when you get an error.

Comment: you should post the full error. I'd assume it's coming from one of the functions you pass `lag` to

Comment: Can you try `x=list(lag)`?

Comment: @Bazingaa: I get o/p with `list(lag)` as well as`np.array(lag)`, but with the above <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7d38ef0> text generated a zillion times, `range` is working for matplotlib.pyplot, so why not for seaborn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 3, `range` returns an iterator, not a list itself. The following does hence not work with python 3. It does however, with python 2.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(9)
y = [1,2,3]*3
sns.pointplot(x=x, y=y, markers = '.')

plt.show()
```

However, you may convert any `range` to a list via `list(range(...))`. Hence the following works fine.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = list(range(9))
y = [1,2,3]*3
sns.pointplot(x=x, y=y, markers = '.')

plt.show()
```

Comment: In python2 , we have type of `range(9)` as `<type 'list'>` i.e, list type and hence, it would work, but as you can see plt.plot works fine with range object in the example above with inflation, so why does sns.pointplot give error: "and can you explain the error, I don't reckon I've called the range object like a function anywhere". Plus, using `list(range(9))` and `np.array(range(9))` works fine, but it generates the <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1fa7c3d0b8>, more than 20 times, which obviously nobody would want to show in their visualization- Why is that happening?

Comment: It's not you who calls the range object, but the seaborn code. If the question is why you can't use python3's `range` with seaborn, you would need to ask the creator of seaborn for why he didn't include that option in the code. Concerning the `Text`s being printed: Your last command is `g.set_xticklabels(..)`, this returns a list of all ticklabels. I guess most people consider is useful that the result of the last line is printed out automatically in IPython, e.g. type `5*3` and you get the result shown in the output.

Comment: Okay, that gets solved if I use `_ = g.set_xticklabels(lag, rotation = 90)`, or by even using _= plt.xticks(rotation=90) , withouth the underscore, plt gives the array value as output! Thanx.